# Running a Python program returns: bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('

Tags: bash, python-3.x, terminal, raspberry-pi, raspbian

This is code for a DSLR timer I'm running on my RaspberryPi. The problem is that whenever I run the file it returns the error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

I'm assuming that the error must relate to one of the characters following a bracket, but I've searched for around an hour and can't find anything. The lower portion of the script I did from scratch, and as I don't have too much experience with python there may be an error (or errors) there as well. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Some of the code was pulled from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eAYxnSU2aw

```
#Imports various modules.
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from sh import gphoto2 as gp
import signal, os, subprocess
import threading


#######################################################################


#Closes the gphoto2 popup.
def killGphoto2Process():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()

    for line in out.splitlines():
        if b'gvfsd-gphoto2' in line:
            pid = int(line.split(None,1)[0])
            os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)

#Creates values for when the pictures were taken. 
shot_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
shot_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

#Names the pictures "Sunrises".
picID = "Sunrises"

#Creates commands to take and download pictures then stores them in the
#variables "triggerCommand" and "downloadCommand".
captureCommand = ["--capture-image"]
downloadCommand = ["--get-all-files"]


#Creates a folder to store captured pictures and gives it a location.
folder_name = shot_date + picID
save_location = "/home/pi/Desktop/gphoto/" + folder_name

#Creates or changes where the pictures are saved.
def createSaveFolder():
    try:
        os.makedirs(save_location)
    except:
        print("Failed to create the new directory.")
    os.chdir(save_location)

#Captures and downloads the pictures.
def captureImages():
    gp(captureCommand)
    gp(downloadCommand)

#Renames the captured images.
def renameFiles(ID):
    for filename in os.listdir("."):
        if len(filename) < 13:
            if filename.endswith(".JPG"):
                os.rename(filename, (shot_time + ID + ".JPG"))


#######################################################################


#Creates a loop that runs every 30 seconds.
def printit():
    threading.Timer(30, printit).start()

    #Imports the "time" module to get the time.
    import time

    #Creates variables for hour and minute.
    hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))
    minutePart1 = int(time.strftime("%M"))
    colon = ":"

    #Puts a "0" in front of "minute" if "minute" is less than 10.
    #This prevents: time(7:9) not equaling sunrise(7:09).
    if minutePart1 < 10:
        minute = ("0" + str(minutePart1))
    else:
        minute = (minutePart1)

    #Converts the time from 24-Hour to 12-Hour.
    if int(hour) > 12:
       hour = hour - 12

    #Creates variables "time" and "sunrise".
    time = (str(hour) + colon + str(minute))
    sunrise = "7:09"

    #Takes a picture if the time is 7:09 AM.
    if time == sunrise :
        killGphoto2Process()
        createSaveFolder()
        captureImages()
        #renameFiles(picID)
        print("Sunrise!")

        print("Currently running \"Camera Controller.py\" ")

    printit()
```

Comment: Your code is python code.  Your error message is bash.  You need to run the code under python, _not_ under bash.  If the code is in a file called script.py, try running `python3 script.py`.

Comment: Or, including a hashbang. Put `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the first line.

Comment: @John1024 Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: @randomir The problem still persists.

Comment: I'm able to run this file on my Mac, after changing a import statement. If you are not able to run it, please share which version of Python you are using. A Syntax error seems to suggest that there is something syntactically  wrong, but I'm able to run this with a Python2 without any Syntax errors. Looking at the code, I can't find anything that will be wrong with Python3. Edit: I just tried it with a Python3 interpreter as well, and no Syntax Errors. Please share more information, or maybe even a screenshot.

Comment: Saying "that didn't work" is not helpful.  What didn't work?  Precisely what error message did you see?

Comment: @John1024 Sorry, the error was the exact same as before: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @ThatOnePost Baloney.  Python and bash are two _different_ programs. 
 __Python does not emit bash errors.__  If you run it as I suggested, you _cannot_ get that bash error.  You need to explain exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @John1024 I'm most definitely doing something wrong, here's a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/QXn0wfd.png

Comment: @kdheepak I'm using Python 3 on a RaspberryPi Running Raspbian and calling the file from the terminal. If you need any more info let me know.  https://i.imgur.com/QXn0wfd.png

Comment: @ThatOnePost Thank you!  That explains it.  Answer written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the imgur image, the problem is:
[image]

Instead of:

```
python3 Camera Controller for Raspberry Pi (Part 4) .py
```

use:

```
python3 'Camera Controller for Raspberry Pi (Part 4) .py'
```

*Without* the quotes, the shell considers `Camera`, `Controller`,  `for`, `Raspberry`,  `Pi`,  `(`, `Part`,  `4`, `)`, and `.py` all to be separate.  Because `(` is shell *metacharacter* in an illegal position, the shell cannot parse this command line.

*With* quotes, the whole of the file name is treated as one argument and is passed to python unharmed.

After making this change, there may very well be additional issues with the python code. As [kdheepak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5451769/kdheepak) noted, there may be problems with an import statement.  For instance, the code imports from a module `sh` but my python installation does not include any module by that name.

Comment: `sh` is a 3rd-party library that tries to offer an idiomatic interface to running arbitrary external programs via liberal use of magic. Inasmuch as it obfuscates what's really going on under the hood, I dislike it intensely -- but while the OP may or may not have it installed (and should really be using `subprocess` instead), it *is* a thing that exists.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I do have sh installed, but I'm open to any ideas on how to improve my code as this is my first shot at this program and I'll likely be changing things anyway.